# Laravelでviewにデータを渡して、ブラウザに表示させたいが躓いています。

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

下記エラーで躓いてます。
どなたかエラー解決への道導を示して下さいませんか。

したい事

```
viewでforeachを利用し各レコードを抽出し、
さらに抽出したレコードに対しアロー演算子でプロパティを指定して、
各カラムのデータを取り出したい。
```

エラー文

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/某/詳細.blade.php)
```

存在しない変数のプロパティやnullの値を参照した時に発生するエラー。

該当ファイル
[詳細.blade.php]

```
<tbody>
@foreach($某 as $★　←テーブル■■■■esの単数形) 
   <tr>
       <td>{{ $某->id }}</td>
campactで指定されている某を$某として使用

=>@foreach($某 as $★) の★部分にどの変数を使えばいいのかがわからなくて躓いている
```

[某Controller.php]

```
public function show某(int $某Id): View
{
   $某 = $this->某Service->retrieve某($某Id);
   return view('某.詳細', compact('★★★★'));
}
```

関連ファイル
[CarInspectionHistory.php]

```
public function 某InspectionHistory(): BelongsTo
{
   return $this->belongsTo(某::class);
}
```

[web.php]

```
Route::get('/某/詳細/{某_id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\某Controller@show某');
```

[某InspectionHistoriesSeeder.php]

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Models\某InspectionHistory::class, 2500)->create();
    }
```

試した事
[1]

```
@foreach($某 as $★)
の$★の部分を
・$★
・$★_inspection_histories
・$★ID
・$★s
に変えてみたけれど同じエラー
```

[2]

```
public function show某(int $某Id): View
{
   $car = $this->某Service->retrieve某($某Id);
   return view('某.detail', compact('某'));
}
の$某を$garsに、compact('某')をcompact('gar')にして、
@foreach($gars as $gar)で試すも同じエラー
```

環境

```
Laravel Framework 5.7.22
docker 18.09.1
```

余裕ある方ご回答願います。

Answer (score 0):

Laravel の view ファイルにおいては、 controller から渡された変数を展開することができます。
例えば、

```
//@controller : ID $id のデータを取得して view に渡す
$data = YourDataClass::find($id);
return view('data.show', compact('data'));
```

とした場合、 view ファイル（resorces/views/data/show.blade.php）では

```
//@view
//controller で compact('data') を渡したので、 $data を使える
//compact の中の文字列と view での変数名が同じになります
{{$data}}
```

でデータを参照できます。

jazzy coffee さんの例で言うならば（すみません、$某を $bou に変更しています）、

```
//@controller
public function showBou(int $bouId): View
{
   $bou = $this->bouService->retrieveBou($bouId);
   return view('bou.show', compact('bou'));
}
```

としておき、

```
//@view
@foreach($bou as $item) 
   <tr>
       <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

とすれば、 controller にてきちんとデータ $bou が取れている限りは view でもデータを展開できるはずです。

cf1. [[laravel] controllerからviewへの変数の受け渡しとその展開方法（@ryo2132 様による Qiita 記事）](https://qiita.com/ryo2132/items/63ced19601b3fa30e6de)
cf2. [compact 関数（php.net）](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.compact.php)

Answer (score 0):

変数名をbouにしますね
idは存在していないエラーなので

**bouController.php**

```
public function show($id): View
{
   $bou = $this->bouService->retrievebou($id);
   return view('bow.detail', compact('bou'));
}
```

**detail.blade.php**

```
<tbody>
@foreach($bou as $b) 
   <tr>
       <td>{{ $b->id }}</td>
   <tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/bou/detail/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\bouController@show');
```

とパラメータの渡し方を調整したら上手く行けると思います